# What does why would I do it mean in this context?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, future-in-the-past

I've often heard people saying this. And even I say it when someone accuses me of doing something that I didn't do.

I'd say:

Why would I do that?

But what's the grammar behind it?

Is it future from the past tense or something or what?
**It's obviously not a conditional construction**

**Context from SE01 EP02 Austin & Ally**

Austin: what does the jacket have
to do with the music video?

Trish: It's a line in Ally's song,
"my jacket's
in the lost and found."

Ally: "my jacket"?
It says "I like it."
The line is "I like it
when you hang around."

Dez: "hang around"?
I thought it said "kangaroo."
♪ I like it
when you kangaroo. ♪.

Ally: Why would I write "I like
it when you kangaroo"?

Comment: Do not delete and repost the same question. Edit the original to include the extra context.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following conditional declarations:

> I would do it if you paid me.
>
> I would do it if my life depended on it.
>
> I would do it if I thought it would make things better.

The question **Why would I do it?**  asks "What possible reason or motive would I have for doing it?

In your example:

"What possible circumstances would lead me to write *I like it when you kangaroo?*"

Comment: but in that context there is no condition

Comment: @user82287: Exactly. With **Why would..?** the question is asking "Under what conditions ...?"    The question is *incredulous*.  By asking, the asker is saying "It is ridiculous or very weird that you would think there would be some conditions under which I would have written that. What could they possibly be???"

Comment: okay it's kind of clear now. but the examples you gave are in present tense. and in my given example it's past. so shouldn't it be why would I have done it? or is why would I do it used for both past and present? that's what I wanna ask

Comment: @user82287     **Why would I write** is not in the past tense.

Comment: but the misread lyrics were already written by her. So shouldn't it be why would I have written it?

Comment: @user82287   She is not referring to that particular act of writing in isolation. Rather she is saying "Why would I *ever* write something like that?"

Comment: had she been talking about that particular act of writing .she'd say why would I have done it. right?  but I never heard someone saying that. I've always heard people saying why would I do it. everytime they're accused of doing something they didn't do. even I do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83404/discussion-between-user82287-and-tomauo).

Answer (score 0):

Question: Why **would** I do that?

Assertion: I would close the window right now. [**implication in the background, which is not always actually spoken**: If I were you or if I were cold.]

Question: Why **do I always close the window**?

Assertion: I a**lways close the window when I am cold.**

would do is conditional.

Person One: You left the dog outside all night and it was cold.

Person Two: Why would I do that?

[If it were cold: background]  Why would I do that?

would do is conditional. The entire idea is not always spelled out clearly in conversations or dialogue but it is always in the background. And the idea is some kind of conditional utterance.

Comment: but the 2nd person did leave the dog outside. then why did he say why would I do that?

Comment: this isn't what I meant. Can I provide the context

Comment: just to make it clear what I meant?